# Why won't list memorize previous inputs and sum them?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With each iteration the list only presents the last appended input and not the sum of the last input + previous appended inputs.

```py
def main_program():
    n = []
    n.append(int(input("insert:\n")))
    print(sum(n))
while True:
    main_program()
    if input("Add another number? (Y/N):\n") == "N":
        break
```

I'm trying to create a "snowball effect" for lack of a better description. I wanted the program to store each appended input and sum them all together.

Comment: `n = []` You are resetting `n` to an empty list every time the function runs.  Move that line of code outside the function, so it only runs once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define `n` just once.

```
def main_program():
    n.append(int(input("insert:\n")))
    print(sum(n))

n = []
while True:
    main_program()
    if input("Add another number? (Y/N):\n") == "N":
        break
```

Passing the list as parameter in the function `main_program` also works, since lists are call-by-reference.